# Create HTML slides with knitr, Rmarkdown and pandoc

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

I am trying to create a HTML slides with  knitr, Rmarkdown and pandoc.
I got a reference from http://rprogramming.net/create-a-slideshow-powerpoint-with-r-knitr-pandoc-and-slidy/.

But I meet a problem at the step5. After executing

```
knit("test4.Rmd")
system("pandoc -s -t slidy test4.md -o test4.html")
```

I got a message

> pandoc.exe: Could not parse YAML header: found character that cannot
>   start any token "source" (line 13, column 1)

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried the new new RStudio preview? It's seamless.

Comment: w/o the Rmd this is pretty much impossible.

Comment: I had tried the new RStudio preview and others previews provide in Rstudio. But that still not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your line 13 in your md file. and change `---` into `-----` or more. This is how I solved my problem.

Obviously it has something to do with YAML header. I just got inspiration from [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520463/pandoc-cannot-parse-yaml-header-when-converting-md-to-pdf), so I figure maybe change the `---` with `----`(just add more `-`)can prevent the pandoc from treating it as a YAML block.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Why does it work? What effects does this change cause?

Comment: I think it has something to do with YAML header. I'm new to the  YAML thing, I just got inspiration from [another stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520463/pandoc-cannot-parse-yaml-header-when-converting-md-to-pdf), so I figure maybe change the `---` with `----`(just add more `-`)can prevent the pandoc from treating it as a YAML block.

Comment: You should edit that into your answer, not just post a comment.